# Best way of progressively testing changing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

The code that I want to test has the purpose of parsing math expressions through using trees.
Therefore, I thought of testing in a progressive manner, where I slowly build up a tree and have a test after each operation, something like so:

```
TreeBuilder.addNode(small, "A=B*C");
it("should return 0 due to using default values", () => {
    expect(small.getValue("A")).to.equal(0);
});

TreeBuilder.changeValue(small, "B", 2);
TreeBuilder.changeValue(small, "C", 3);

it("should update parent value after changing leaves", () => {
    expect(small.getValue("A")).to.equal(6);
});
```

And so on - the details don't matter, but you get the idea. Now, obviously, this doesn't work since all the statements outside of the "it"s get executed at once, so I cannot have such "progressive tests".

Of course, I could have a different data object for each of the tests, but I don't like that solution, since that would be quite cumbersome.

**So my question is more one of best practices than specific code: How do you best test behavior that progressively develops over multiple function calls?**

Comment: This is a bit opiniated, but it is considered a good practice to make tests not depend on each other. This would mean having a different data object for each test so they can run independently. Another way would to create one big `it` block and do something like "setup -> expect -> change -> expect next -> change -> expect next". This is considered a bad practice though since your test would essentially be multiple tests in one. Effectively, this does achieve the same thing you're trying to do though - run the expectations sequentially.

Comment: Just noticed, but in your specific example here you could also just wrap your `TreeBuilder.addNode(small, "A=B*C");` in a `beforeEach()` and everything that depends on your changes in a `describe` using another `beforeEach()` in your describe block.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to make each test independent from each other (like @pascalpuetz said), but to do what you want you can use the mocha before function:

```js
describe("parser", () => {
    var shared_var;

    before(() => {
        // setup code here
        shared_var = ....
    });

    it("should ...", () => {
       expect(shared_var).to...
    });

    it("should ...", () => {
       expect(shared_var).to....
    });

});
```

Comment: The thing is that the before would not be the same for each it. Since my object would look different before each test, literally only the very first line/function call would be able to be in the before var.

Comment: In my snippet the `before` function call runs once, before all the `it` (while beforeEach would run before each `it`).

Comment: I realize that, but there would basically only be one line of code in the before call. The question of where I would put the rest of my calls that progressively build my object therefore still remains

Comment: That's exactly the ugly part. The object modification code has to go inside the `it` function, making each subsequent `it` depending on the previous ones. What I would do instead, is re-building the object from scratch inside each `it` and then perform the `expect` checks. It's a lot of code repetition, but it keeps the tests independent.